# Hash-based filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, hashsum

Is there a hash-based filesystem, where:

- There is a store of blocks (perhaps 512b, 4KB or 128KB) indexed by the hash of their contents.
- Each block has a usage count.  When it reaches zero, the block's storage is freed.
- Files are just a length and a list of the block hashes.

This would enable many optimisations, such as:

- Large files can be copied almost for free (in terms of both time and required storage).
- Copies of large files use Copy-on-Write to store alterations with minimal disk usage.
- File equality becomes quick to calculate.

Does such a filesystem already exist?

If not, is it not feasible or is it not a good idea?

Comment: What about 0 length files? They all have the same hash. What about copied files? Both original and copy have the same hash.

Comment: 0 length files have no blocks, so no blocks need to be stored for them.  Copied files shared their blocks, with reference counting, so that the only space a copied file occupies is its length field and the list of its block's hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about a copy-on-write filesystem with deduplication.  Both [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) and [Btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) work like this to some degree.  Btrfs has [offline deduplication](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Deduplication) tools that can merge duplicate blocks some time after they've been written.  [ZFS can do online deduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Deduplication).

Is online deduplication a good idea?  It depends on your use case, but probably not.  According to the Wikipedia article for ZFS, "effective use of deduplication may require large RAM capacity; recommendations range between 1 and 5 GB of RAM for every TB of storage."  Offline deduplication is probably practical in many more cases.

Comment: It you don't mind a reaper you could save vast tracts of kernel allocated memory with offline deduplication. Have the filesystem maintain block checksums and provide a syscall mechanism whereby a user-space process could read the list of block checksums and merge identical blocks